# Изменение размера подчиненных виджетов при изменении размера родительского (Qt).

Tags: qt, c++

Форма создана в дизайнере. На нее добавлен GridLayout. Как сделать, чтобы при изменении размера формы (например, когда необходимо развернуть) соответственно изменялся и размер GridLayout'а вместе с его содержимым? Необходимо, чтобы содержимое заполняло всю форму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю как сказать, но надо чтобы лейаут не просто так лежал на форме, а для формы задан этот лейаут. В обычном виде это

```
this->setLayout(m_gridLayout);
```

а если в дизайнере -- то выделить форму и щёлкнуть на "Скомпоновать по сетке" (в QtCreator **Ctrl+G**).

Comment: Спасибо. Про `setLayout` я как-то забыл совсем, а про дизайнер и не знал.